# How to fetch data from oracle database in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, oracle, configuration

FYI - I have only the DB details by which can I connect to oracle DB. How can fetch the data in AngularJS directly. I am not planning to use any backend. Like by giving oracleDB details I can configure and fetch data.

Any help is most welcome. Please let me know if anyone has worked or any suggestion or Is it possible to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your oracle DB stored if you dont use a backend?

Comment: I think you will need a server technology to fetch the data for you and then return it as JSON to angular. Otherwise this database will be exposed to every user that can get hands on the javascript code for your application and I don't think it is even possible to directly connect to database from angular ...

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Web Services for XML DB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_web_services.htm#CHDDBCHB) running on your database, you can make web service calls to your database directly from code running in the browser. Otherwise you will need a server to transfer requests to and from your web client to and from the database server.